# Mock all transformers in ETL chain to a single Mock

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito, integration-testing

Im working on an ETL app where the ETL chain is maintained in Spring beans. Something like:

```
<bean id="extractor" children="t1" />
<bean id="t1" children="t2" />
<bean id="t2" children="t3" />
<bean id="t3" children=null />
```

And the classes look like:

```
class Transformer {
    Transformer [] children = [Transformer with secret S2]
    String secret = "S1";
    public doSomething() {
        
    }
}

Class Transformer {
    Transformer [] children = [Transformer with secret S3]
    String secret = "S2";
    public doSomething() {

    }
}

Class Transformer {
    Transformer [] children = null;
    String secret = "S3";
    public doSomething() {
        
    }
}
```

And the extractor looks like:

```
class Extractor  {
    public transform(Transformer n) {
        n.doSomething();
        for(Transformer c: n.children) {
            extractor(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Transformers have database related data and hence would like to mock them.
One option is the duplicate the Spring bean etl chain with mocked transformers but I dont like duplication. Plus it would hard to maintain.
I also dont want a separate mock for each Transformer.

I have access to the real instance of Extractor but once extractor() starts, I would like to mock doSomething() of all instances of Transformer.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

So to solve this I added a `ETLBeanPostProcessor` bean in my spring context.
In it I did something like

```
class PostProcessor implements ETLBeanPostProcessor {
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(final Object bean, final String beanName) throws BeansException {
        @Override
        if (bean instanceof Transformer) {
            final Transformer transformer = (Transformer) Mockito.spy(bean);
            // mock whatever you want
            return transformer;
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

This way I can do something specific for all instances of `Transformer`.